# AjaxControlToolkit 3.0.30930.0 vs System.web.extension

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I recently started to use AjaxControlToolkit v3.0.30930.0 in my application together with System.Web.Extension 3.5.

My development environment is Visual Studio 2005, .NET Framework 2.0 and the development language is C#.

The Ajax control I used is the ModalPopupExtender. I also used the UpdatePanel and updateprogress controls.

Everything is working fine on my development machine. But I got a problem after I deployed the application to a server which does not have System.Web.Extension 3.5 installed, which is understandable.

My question is, can the ajax controls I used work without System.Web.Extension 3.5? Say I revert the ajaxcontroltoolkit back to version 1.0.61025.0? I don't have the option to install .NET 3.5 as yet.

Thank you for your help.

John

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution to my question.

Here is what I did.

I set my project to reference version 1.0.61025.0 of system.web.extension dll and version 1.0.20229.20821 of ajaxcontroltoolkit. Then I updated all the relevant settings to tell .NET runtime to load version 1.0.61025.0 of system.web.extension dll. It worked out fine.

Hope this is of some help to somebody.

John